# Rest-assured cannot handle Post with x-www-form-urlencoded and Oauth1

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, rest-assured

I got a problem when posting to API with Rest-assured for testing framework and `CodeIgniter` with Oauth1 as API backend,

`$this->input->post` cannot handle query param, so i decided to choose `formParam` ,

But, when i launch the test case , it said `oauth_problem` and invalid signature

Can anyone help me? Thanks

In my rest-assured test case

```
        String result = given().
            header("return-type","text/json").
            contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").
            formParam("offer_price","33330").
            auth().oauth(OauthData.CONSUMER_KEY, OauthData.CONSUMER_SECRET, OauthData.TOKEN_BUYER, OauthData.TOKEN_SECRET_BUYER).
    expect().
                statusCode(200).
    when().
    post(OauthData.API_BASE + "/v1/offer/" + "56b484ca36913473000041b0")
            .asString();
```